# Conditional update value

Tags: sql, r

I have a dataframe called dfData in R as below;

```
x   y 
10  A
20  B
30  C
40  D
```

I am trying to achieve the following;

if the value in X is 10, update the value to "XYZ"

Is there a function or elegant way to do this in R? Trying to avoid multiple ifelse statements.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need just a single replacement? Or are there many more values you want to change?

Comment: As per your description you dont need *multiple* ifelse. Just one. Otherwise, you could use `replace`

Comment: For elegance, there's `DT[x == 10, y := "XYZ"]` when using data.table. Alternately, yeah, `replace` isn't bad: `transform(DF, y = replace(y, x == 10, "XYZ"))` or something. If you have more values to conditionally assign, there's an "update join" with data.table...  http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#joins-update you'd need to post a more complete example for that, though.

Comment: @docendo There are several values i want to change..

Comment: why is this tagged SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to replace many y values depending on x values, one posible approach is:

```
# define df as data.table
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90), y= c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A'))

> df
    x y
1: 10 A
2: 20 B
3: 30 C
4: 40 D
5: 50 A
6: 60 B
7: 70 C
8: 80 D
9: 90 A

# define your pair of values for replacement
a <- c(10,20,50)
b <- c('XYZ', 'ZYX', 'AAA')

# x = 10 will cause y to be replaced by 'XYZ', x= 20 will cause y to be replaced by 'ZYX' and so on ...

# replacement 

for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  df[ x==a[i], y := b[i]]
}

> df
    x   y
1: 10 XYZ
2: 20 ZYX
3: 30   C
4: 40   D
5: 50 AAA
6: 60   B
7: 70   C
8: 80   D
9: 90   A
```

vectors a and b could have any length BUT need to be paired with value x and value y.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(10,20,30,40)

y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

df1 <- data.frame(x,y)


df1$y <- as.character(df1$y)

Now we get the data frame as you want:

> df1
   x y
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
4 40 d

> df1[which(df1$x==10),2] <- 'xyz'

This produces:

> df1
   x   y
1 10 xyz
2 20   b
3 30   c
4 40   d
```

Comment: thanks but in my case its the same valuei want to update...i basically want 10 to become xyz.